# Can't dual boot on my Toshiba laptop

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, toshiba-laptop, bootrepair, toshiba-hard-drive

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my Toshiba Satellite C55-B5299. At first, GRUB was not booting at all. I used `boot-repair` to try to fix this. However, whenever I boot, I get this...

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

...then the computer boots into Windows, just as before. What should I do to remedy this? Thanks so much, as I am a noob.

Comment: I would reinstall Ubuntu but using some guide/tutorial for dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows on UEFI firmware (look on Ubuntu site). Don't expect instructions for this on Microsoft site ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as i can see, you installed the **EFI** version of the OS when the system does not detect the images needed to this kind of boot.
Maybe installing a **BIOS boot** version would help, or maybe is problem of the installation that does not installed the needed boot files.
I recommend ensure your system boot with BIOS or EFI, and try to install the correspondent system again following the ubuntu setup windows that is very well designed.